# jQuery attach onclick function to element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I have four image buttons with onclick events attached to them two pairs of two. I'm trying to replace those image buttons with text buttons and reattach the onclick function to the next text buttons. These buttons are not always on the page and I'm confined to using jQuery 1.4 otherwise `.prop` would make this a lot easier.

Consider this HTML:

```
<input type="image" src="path/to/image.gif" class="one" onclick="function()" />
<input type="image" src="path/to/image.gif" class="one" onclick="function()" />
<input type="image" src="path/to/image2.gif" class="two" onclick="function()" />
<input type="image" src="path/to/image2.gif" class="two" onclick="function()" />
```

I wrote the following jQuery code to get the onclick function, the inputs and rebind the onclick function.

```
$('input.one').each(function(){
  var oneOnClick = $(this).attr('onclick');
  $(this).replaceWith('<input type="button" value="one" class="one" onclick="'+oneOnClick+'" />');
)};
```

And the same for `.two`. I found out that the way the value of the onclick attribute is returned in jQuery means this cannot be done.

Using some resources online I updated my code to look like this:

```
var oneOnClick = $('input.one').first().attr('onclick');
var twoOnClick = $('input.two').first().attr('onclick');

$('input.one').each(function(){
  $(this).replaceWith('<input type="button" class="one" value="one"/>');
});
$('input.two').each(function(){
  $(this).replaceWith('<input type="button" class="two" value="two"/>');
});

$('input.one').live("click", oneOnClick);
$('input.two').live("click", twoOnClick);
```

But I'm getting an error

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'b.split')

when `input.one` doesn't exist.

How can I make this work?

Comment: what version of `jquery` you are using?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao 1.4.4

Comment: Your _Using some resources online updated code_ is confusing!! where does `next_page_img` exists in document

Comment: what about `var twoOnClick = $('input.next_page_img').first().attr('onclick');`. It should be `input.two` if I am not wrong!!

Comment: why don't you just call the function directly in `.live` instead of taking it as `attr` from `image`? Any specific reasons?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao because the `attr` from `image` is dynamically generated by our server. Sometimes the `onclick` can be `onclick="function2()"` other times `onclick="function3()"`

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code to bind onClick event

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.one').each(function(){
       $(this).attr('type',"button");
    });
});
```

Comment: Can't do that. Internet Explorer's Kryptonite

Comment: @henryaaron - you use `.attr()` in the example. why is this answer a concern for IE then?

Comment: @wahwahwah Changing the type of an input is not allowed in many versions of Internet Explorer

Answer (score 0):

Well I suggest you to go with your first opted method:

Check this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/0ta6ampn/)**

```
function clickOne()
{
    alert('hi');
}
function clickTwo()
{
    alert('helleo');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var oneOnClick = $('input.one').first().get(0).attributes.onclick.nodeValue;
    var twoOnClick = $('input.two').first().get(0).attributes.onclick.nodeValue;
    $('input.one').each(function(){
        $(this).replaceWith('<input type="button" value="one" class="one" onclick="'+oneOnClick+'" />');
    });

    $('input.two').each(function(){
        $(this).replaceWith('<input type="button" value="two" class="two" onclick="'+twoOnClick+'" />');
    });
    $('input.one').live("click", oneOnClick);
    $('input.two').live("click", twoOnClick);
});
```

> **POINT TO NOTE:**
>
> - **`$('input.one').attr('onclick')`** or **`$('input.two').attr('onclick')`** holds the value of the **`onclick`** attribute (which is a string). However, because the browsers treat the event attributes in a different way, they are
>     returned with **`function onclick() { clickOne() }`** and you know
>     about this. Thus, if you want to directly call the function, you'll
>     have to either strip the
>     **`function() {}`** or call it immediately or get it using
>     **`get(0).attributes.onclick.nodeValue`**
> - wrap **`clickOne`** and **`clickTwo`** in `head` and remaining things    on **`document.ready`**

Comment: Your code breaks when the buttons are not on the page. `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$('input.one').first().get(0).attributes')`

Comment: Then before getting button place a if condition to check if it exists or not like `if($('.input.one').length>0)` get the value.

Comment: Getting this error when I do that. I don't understand it at all `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'b.split')`

Comment: I doubt it might be from some other source not from the above code. Just check where you are getting that `error` message!

Comment: What is the point of this? `var inputOneElement = $('input[type="image"].one');      var inputTwoElement = $('input[type="image"].two');`

Comment: That actually I kept while exploring different ways to get it done!! No need to that. **[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/0ta6ampn/3/)**